# A YouTube video about "The matrix"

Tags: story-identification, the-matrix

I remember a YouTube channel similar to "*Cinema Sins"* but for good points instead of bad ones.

Now, I'm specifically *not* taking about "*Cinema Wins*", I found them and they are not the one I remember.

I remember the movie *The Matrix* getting an extremely high score (for example, I remember them getting points for "Neo" and "one" having the same letters, and a bunch of biblical references), also *The Matrix* video was uploaded way before the one from "*Cinema Wins*", at least 5 years ago, probably closer to 10 years ago.

They had some "multipliers" and other concepts from video games for the point system. I think The Matrix got above 1 million points total.

Comment: Well at least they’ve got a solid and objective system for assessing movie quality, whoever they are.

Comment: Wouldn't call it objective by any means but it was fun, at least in my opinion...